# Swift iOS Sound Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, memory-leaks

Was bug testing my app and noticed something interesting whenever a sound-file played (any sound file). I noticed that the smaller sound files would add about 0.01 mb of memory and not release the memory after, and the longer ones after done playing would add about 1.8 - 2.0 mb.

I used instruments leak check to test the app and see what exactly was going on and I gathered that it was indeed the audio-files.

I usually play my audio-files using an SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(). Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

```
let gameOver = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("gameOver.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
sprite.runAction(gameOver)
```

Not sure if this is a problem with just me or if its a known problem. Or is it even a problem at all? Just was curious.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybZq8.png)

Comment: Can you post some code about how you create and play the sound?

Comment: Yes, ill update the post with some code.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this. If anyone knows, I would be very interested to learn why.

Comment: This is a bug in iOS and other developers have commented on Stackoverflow. I'm still researching a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few months ago, so I tried the `AudioToolbox` framework as an alternative and it works just as well with no memory leaks.

I had a handful of sound effects I wanted to use for a game so I created a function like bellow which sets up all the `systemSoundID` in the sfx array.

```
var sfx = [SystemSoundID]()


func createSfx() {

    var i = 0

    while i < 8 {

        var fileName = ""

        switch i {

        case 0:
           fileName = "coinCollected"

        case 1:
            fileName = "laserGun"

        case 2:
            fileName = "laserBeamShutOff"

        case 3:
            fileName = "powerDown"

        case 4:
            fileName = "shipMovement"

        case 5:
            fileName = "openBlockade"

        case 6:
            fileName = "invisibilityOn"

        case 7:
            fileName = "outOfFuel"

        default:
            print("Error creating sfx")

        }

        sfx.append(SystemSoundID())

        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "wav")
        let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &sfx[i])

        i += 1

    }

}
```

You can then play a sound effect using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` with the array index of the sound effect like:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sfx[1]) // Plays laserGun sound effect
```

Also just so you know, there is one issue I found when using this. The volume of the sound effects won't increase past the halfway point on the device if your using an `AVAudioPlayer`to play background music. I'm not sure why this happens but I wasted a lot of time trying to find an alternative for sound effects and this was the best bet, despite the slight volume issue.

Hope this helps some people that are looking for a good alternative to the SKAction.